# example about memory ordering in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, atomic

Consider following example:

```
 -Thread 1-
 y.store (20, memory_order_relaxed);
 x.store (10, memory_order_release);

 -Thread 2-
 if (x.load(memory_order_acquire) == 10) {
     assert (y.load(memory_order_relaxed) == 20)
     y.store (10, memory_order_release)
 }

 -Thread 3-
 if (y.load(memory_order_acquire) == 10)
     assert (x.load(memory_order_relaxed) == 10)
```

In this example second `assert` will fire(am i correct?). is it because there is no store to `x` in thread 2 before `y.store (10, memory_order_release)`?

(in cppreference.com they say this sentence about `release`: "A store operation with this memory order performs the release operation: prior writes to other memory locations become visible to the threads that do a consume or an acquire on the same location.")

Can i change the order of store to `y` in thread2 from `release` to `sec/cst` to solve the problem?

Comment: No `assert` can fire.. Interestingly, even if the order of store to `y` in thread2 is changed to `relaxed`, still no `assert` can fire because that does not break the chain of happen-before events (thread 3 still needs to use `acquire` though)

Answer (score 2):

Your example isn't complete because you haven't specified initial values for x & y.  But let's assume that the thread that starts all threads has initialized both to 0.

Then if thread 2 does a store to y, it must have read from thread 1's store to x and synchronized with it.  If thread 3's load from y reads thread 2's store to y, it must synchronize also.  Therefore, the store to x in thread 1 must happen before the load in thread 3 and it must happen after the initialization store to x.  Thus thread 3's x.load must get the value of 10.  Happens before in the absence of consume is transitive.

I suggest using CDSChecker on these examples to see what values are possible.

Comment: See example of overall summery section of http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync there they say second assert will fire.

Comment: The GCC example declares different memory orderings, so it is not relevant.